# Facebook Graph API - Get only the recent checkins of a page/place

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-page, checkin

Is there any way to get **only** the **number** of checkins that occurred recently to a Facebook **page/place** ?

I know I'm able to get the checkins using something like this:

```
GET \ "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/{{page-id}}?fields=checkins&access_token=..."
```

But it seems to return **all** the checkins of the page since it was created. Can I get **only the recent** checkins somehow ?

Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/insights

Comment: Thank you CBroe, but I think this won't help me. I guess I can only get the page insights if I have the access token of the user that owns it (or of the page itself). Am I wrong ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. For pages you don’t have admin access to, that kind of data is rather none of your business in the first place.

Comment: Got it. Thank you